# Value of radio button to JS

Tags: javascript, html

How can I get the value in a radio button to the JavaScript file , I could read the contents in textbox and some others but not from radio button.

Comment: Do you need to select the radio button with JS? or do you need to change the value?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go jquery is from javascript

```js
$('input').click(function(){
a=$(this).val();
alert(a);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='radio' value='valueofwhat' name='anyname'>
<input type='radio' value='valueofwhatsecond' name='anyname'>
```

Comment: @Rahul R is this what u try to achieve?